# Laravel 8 latest login controller code | phone number login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, custom-authentication

I have several ways to log in with my phone number except for the default Laravel email. But failed. Here I added the full code of my login controller below.

**In loginControlller.php:** I added this

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class LoginController extends Controller {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */

        public function validateLogin(Request $request) {
            dd($request->all());
        }

        use AuthenticatesUsers;

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct() {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }

        public function username(){
            return 'phone';     
        }
    }
```

**In login.blade.php:** I added this

```
    <div>
        <x-label for="phone" :value="__('Phone')" />
        <x-input id="phone" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="phone" :value="old('phone')" required autofocus />
    </div>
```

Whenever I tried, this occurred
[image]

Comment: You have used starter kits like jetstream or fortify?

Comment: check request has phone ,

Comment: @MohammadHosseini no, i used ui auth

Comment: @JohnLobo where? can you please specify clearly

Comment: public function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {  
 
 dd($request->all());
       
    } .add that method in login controller

Comment: @JohnLobo added but nothing changed

Comment: no, same this occured

Comment: can you join in anydesk?

Comment: i think your page hitting some other method. or else it will show somethink like array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "XHRtv7Rj6h42omSZfvthdnuq8qa1fax1FAynxbRo"
  "username" => "123456"
  "password" => "admin"
]

Comment: Do you overwrite LoginController? or just change the ```username```?

Comment: just added the username()

Comment: no keep username() method as it is and then add public function validateLogin(Request $request) { dd($request->all()); }  method too

Comment: kept the both method

Comment: dd request is not found.

Comment: can you join in anydesk just to check?

Comment: psot you full login controller in question

Comment: check the post , i edited

Comment: add method after username method

Comment: added, but same error occured.

Comment: can you update question with latest login controller code

Comment: updated the question